# Tap-target-view in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

how to create guideline for my app similar [Android TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView) ?
or how to create guideline in angular similar [Android TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView) ?
[react TapTargetView](https://github.com/prscX/react-native-taptargetview) 
[nativescript TapTargetView](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-app-tour)
There is no TapTargetView plugin for ionic or angular?